# setting jQuery .css() within "for .. in" loop

Tags: jquery

1) this works OK:

```
$(container_elm).css({
  'border-width':'1px'
})
```

2) now I am trying to pass css propertyName : value as a parameter to a function:

```
function my_func(css_arr) {
  if (css_arr!==null && css_arr!=='') {
    for(var x in css_arr) {
      if(css_arr.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        y=css_arr[x];
        x_new='"'+x+'"';
        y_new='"'+y+'"';

        $(container_elm).css({
            //'border-width':'1px' // this works
            //x:y // this does NOT work
            //x_new:y_new // this does NOT work
        });
        //console.log(x_new, y_new); //returns "border-width" "1px"
        //console.log(x, y); //returns border-width 1px
      }
    }
  }
}

//usage
my_func({'border-width':'1px'});
```

Any idea on how to pass css object "propertyName : value", and make .css() receive it and work?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: 
demo - http://jsfiddle.net/BRwzF/5/

Comment: what's the result of the `console.log`s?

Comment: Maybe you could provide a working example in a http://jsfiddle.com ?

Comment: SomeKittens: added console.log output to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally agree with what @Somkittens suggested. Just want to brief you about why `x_new:y_new` did not work for you.

In `.css()` jquery function, a key/property does not get parsed or treated as a variable, so putting `$('dom').css('width': '100px')` or `$('dom').css(width: '100px')` does not make any difference. We wrap properties in quotes in case it has hyphens in it. i.e. border-radius, -webkit-border-radius etc.

But still if you want to go with your solution, in that case you have tweak your code a bit which does the same thing as @SomeKittens's

```
 y=css_arr[x];
 x_new=x;
 y_new=y;
 var foobar = {};
     foobar[x_new] = y_new;
 $(container_elm).css(foobar);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4tBVH/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mucking about with `x` and `x_new`, etc, if you're passing in JSON already, why not do this:

```
$(container_elm).css(
    css_arr
);
```

Comment: good idea, but I get "SyntaxError: invalid object initialize" in firebug console

Comment: sorry, my fault, yes it works. But any idea why the code with for in loop does not work?

Comment: You're using the `for...in` loop incorrectly.  There's no need for it here.

Comment: now I see I don't need for...in here. But anyway how should I use correctly in my case?

Comment: @ihtus no need for the function altogether just use `$(el).css({'border-width':'1px'})`. You can pass a complete object and also something like `{"left":"+=20"}`

Comment: Christoph: the func from question is simplified, it's part from a bigger func.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `for` to do this.
`css_arr` is an object with css style. You can pass it directly to the `.css()`.
Example: `$(container_elm).css(css_arr);`

**Suggestion**: Change `css_arr` to `style`.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/sx3nc/2/)

Comment: thank you. But any idea why the code with for in loop does not work?